# Solution for java.sql.SQLException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction

Tags: sql, jdbc, weblogic

I'm running a J2EE MDB in a Weblogic 10.3 clustered environment.

Within one of the methods in the code I create a JDBC connection and turn off auto commit. The connection to the database is made through a XA enabled Data source. The reason for turning the auto-commit off is because I'm using a temp table.

When I'm done with the temp table & other SQL queries I commit the Transaction and turn auto-commit back on. For the most part this has not been a problem but I received the following exception when executing the method, the exception occurred on the line in the code where I issue the commit.

Not sure why I received as in the method I only make calls to a single database, I wonder if its because the data source is XA enabled? Any insight as to why this exception occurs and why it only occurs sometimes would be greatly appreciated

```
java.sql.SQLException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:403)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.disallowGlobalTxnMode(PhysicalConnection.java:6139)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3320)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3357)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.commit(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:130)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.commit(XAConnection.java:844)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.commit(JTAConnection.java:326)
    at com.myPackage.myApp.myDBCaller.tempTableMethod(myDBCaller.java:390)
    at com.myPackage.myApp.myDBCaller.start(myDBCaller.java:153)
    at com.myPackage.myApp.myDBCaller.onMessage(myDBCaller.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1683.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:281)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:187)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:154)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:114)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:114)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at $Proxy228.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:518)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:423)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:325)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4547)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4233)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3709)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:114)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5058)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Comment: Is that connection enlisted in a distributed transaction? If so you **cannot** use `commit()` or `setAutoCommit()`.

Comment: @Mark, What do you mean by enlisted? Within the method that I'm receiving the exception I'm requesting a Connection from the data source. within the method, the only outside calls I'm making are to one database. Is there a way to see if the connection is enlisted in a distributed transaction or not? What's odd is that this exception has only appeared once out of 5 or 6 times that it has been invoked

Comment: The data source where the connection is being grabbed from is XA enabled and does participate in distributed transactions for a different application. Should I create a different data source that is not XA enabled to be used for my application?

Answer (score 0):

Try set property

> `<property name="AutomaticEnlistingEnabled" value="false"/>`

of xaDatasource.

Comment: Where do I have to put it?

Comment: In Spring context.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592730/derby-bitronix-camel-cannot-commit-a-resource-enlisted-in-a-global-transaction